# Opencv: It seems that your device does not support camera(or it is locked)

Tags: android, opencv

I use face_detection of opencv 2.4.5 with Android 4.2.2 on my samsung tablet of Android 4.0.4. The application could use the front camera to calibrate my face. However, when I use this application to play video and face_detection simultaneously, it warns that: "It seems that your device does not support camera(or it is locked)". Do you have any idea of what is happening? Actually, I get the code from a previous application, and  the application can run smoothly in his computer and tablet, so I guess there may not be any coding problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just enable camera permission on the device settings. Works for Tango Device Phab2 (23API)
Setting -> Apps -> Your App -> Enable Camera Permission.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. I added a library to the face_detection codes, and something wrong in "OpenCV Library - 2.4.5/src/org.opencv.android/JavaCameraView.java" The line 127 "mCamera.setParameters(params);" failed to run, so i annotated it, and the warn disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem early today. Please, make sure you have placed the camera permissions on your AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was not a permissions problem.
I was working on a new object (MyCamera) that was extending the JavaCameraView class.
The problem was in the layout file.
Fix: I had to go back with the JavaCameraView object and I edited my layout element accordingly.
From:

```
<com.project.MyCamera>
```

To:

```
<org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView>
```