# It seems that your device does not support camera

Tags: android, opencv, camera, locked

I have come across an error which I guess is very common in OpenCV apps. When I try to run the app, it says "it seems that your device does not support camera(or it is locked)". I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20666366/it-seems-that-your-device-does-not-support-cameraor-it-is-locked) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987361/opencv-it-seems-that-your-device-does-not-support-cameraor-it-is-locked) and I have already done whatever they have said, like granting camera permission and rebooting the device etc. But still problem persists. I know this problem means that any other app must be using camera and hence it is locked. When I clear the cache of all the apps using camera which might me using camera, then it works but just once. After that same issue. Any solution to this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: I am not really sure about solution to your problem but few days back I had the same issue and it turn out that there was some problem in DEFAULT CAMERA.So check if the default camera is set properly.

Comment: @Rahulgalgali: can you elaborate please? set camera in eclipse or phone?

Comment: I know this is probably the first thing you've looked into, but are you certain you're releasing the camera afterwards or disabling the view where the camera preview is being shown?

Answer (score 6):

I have just run into the same problem with OpenCV for Android, and found that going to the phone's ***Settings*** -> ***Apps*** (or similar) -> ***Your app*** -> ***Permissions*** and enabling the `Camera` permission seems to solve the problem.

Hope this helps.

---

**Update**

As noted by @F43nd1r in the comments below, asking the user to update their permissions in the app settings menu should not be done for your own apps. What should be done is to ask the user for permission to access the camera/whatever, as per https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html.

Comment: Note that Runtime permission start from Android Marshmallow. On devices with lower APIs this won't be the problem. Also: Apps can request the user to grant such permissions. This is what apps should do, instead of asking them to go into the settings.

Comment: It was runtime permissions for me

Comment: As per F43nd1r's comments, this is new runtime permissions from Marshmallow onward: see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32347532/android-m-permissions-confused-on-the-usage-of-shouldshowrequestpermissionrati) , [this explanation](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en) , and [this Developer page](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Answer (score 0):

I actually received this error in BlueStack but I solved it by going to Task Manager and ending all the processes of BlueStack. Started BlueStack again and it is working perfect. You can do same if you encounter this problem on your phone. Just restart the phone and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Edit org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView.java and search

```
Szie frameSize = calculateCameraFrameSize(sizes, new JavaCameraSizeAccessor(), width, height);
```

Replace with follow

```
Size frameSize;
                if(width>height)
                {
                    frameSize = calculateCameraFrameSize(sizes, new JavaCameraSizeAccessor(), width, height);
                }
                else
                {
                    frameSize = calculateCameraFrameSize(sizes, new JavaCameraSizeAccessor(), height, width);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html):

> Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to
>   apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.

It means that on new Android devices you also need to request a runtime permission to use, for instance, the camera.

I posted an answer with the piece of code you need to the [question you mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20666366/it-seems-that-your-device-does-not-support-cameraor-it-is-locked).

Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44087946/4398784

*Hope it helps!*

Answer (score 0):

Changing the line **143** in the `JavaCameraView.java` (opencv for android library)

```
Size frameSize = calculateCameraFrameSize(sizes, new JavaCameraSizeAccessor(), width, height);
```

to

```
Size frameSize = new Size(width,height);//calculateCameraFrameSize(sizes, new JavaCameraSizeAccessor(), width, height);
```