# shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale not working as expected

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm working on checking and getting permission from user with API level 23 and above. So here is a confusing thing for me, android.com says:

> shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale() method returns true if the app has requested this permission previously and the user denied the request. 
>   If the user turned down the permission request in the past and chose the Don't ask again option in the permission request system dialog, this method returns false

in other side it gives following code for checking permission and request permission if its neccessery

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

// Should we show an explanation?
if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

    // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
    // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
    // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

} else {

    // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

    // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
    // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
    // result of the request.
    }
}
```

`else` scope in above example runs  if user doesn't allow permission and check **Don't Ask Again**, Right? So with this code user never being asked for permission at first time run. I tested that code and the result is what I expected.
So How could I request permission for first time run and do something if user previously denied my request and do something if user deny my request and check **Don't Ask Again**?

Comment: _"So with this code user never being asked for permission at first time run"_  `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` is supposed to return `false` if your app hasn't asked the user for the permission yet, so the `else` clause would be executed on the first run.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android M Permissions : Confused on the usage of shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32347532/android-m-permissions-confused-on-the-usage-of-shouldshowrequestpermissionrati)

Comment: @Michael but android.com thinks differently :  If the user turned down the permission request in the past and chose the Don't ask again option in the permission request system dialog, this method returns false.

Comment: @BhuvaneshBs I have read this, Mine is not duplicate

Comment: @ArtinArtin: Note the part where it says "returns true if the app has requested this permission previously and the user denied the request"

Comment: I agree with @BhuvaneshBS - this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32347532/android-m-permissions-confused-on-the-usage-of-shouldshowrequestpermissionrati - both questions are asking basically "how to tell the difference between first time run and don't ask again cases". and the answer is in muthuraj's answer to that question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40639430/191761

Answer (score 4):

You can do the following.

1. Ask permission every time by only checking that permission is not granted already. Don't handle the **"Don't ask again"** in this method. (if user checks **"Don't ask again"** the OS will automatically handle and will not ask for permission again and will give a call back of permission denied)
2. Handle the **ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()** in the call back method onRequestPermissionsResult().

Here is my code in which I am asking for permission everytime

```
public void checkAndAskCameraPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_ID);
        }
    }
```

This is how I handles the call back

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_ID: {
                if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {

                  // Do something if permission is not granted and the user has also checked the **"Don't ask again"**
                } else if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                    // Do something if permission not granted
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

first check if the permission is granted then do what you need
else if permission is denied then check weather you should request the permission you need or not through shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale.

if shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale return false then you can just show a message to the user to told them to enable the permission manually.
other then if shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale return true then request the permission and get the result of granting permission in onRequestPermissionsResult

**update , this is just a simple code to show the steps:**

```
if (checkSelfPermission == granted){
 // do what you want 
 } else if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale == true) {
        // you can request the permission you want from the user, then check whether permission granted or not inside onRequestPermissionsResult method
 } else { 
        // here you know the permission is not granted , and also the user check on "Dont ask Again!" checkbox, so all you can to do is just tell the user to enable the permission manually from app permissions through Toast message or any thing else
        }
```

Comment: First I will check if permission is not granted, so in that scope I would check if I shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale so I tell user you denied my request for first time but again I ask you for it. in else I would tell user I can't offer you to allow my request because you checked the **Dont ask Again**! So How could I make my app ready for all situations?!

Comment: you are right, but in first app run time and in other hand when user checked **Dont ask Again** the **else** section will execute! Are you agree with that? else section will execute in two situation! If I tell user that should enable permission in settings in else section, it will appear at very first time run,too!

Comment: @ArtinArtin first, sorry about mistake in second condition, and about when user checked **Dont ask Again** the else section will execute? no, it will be executed only if user just deny the permission without checked **Dont ask Again!**, but if user checked the checkbox and also press on deny, then the last else statement will be executed.

Comment: `else { 
        // here you know the permission is not granted , and also the user check on "Dont ask Again!" checkbox, so all you can to do is just tell the user to enable the permission manually from app permissions through Toast message or any thing else
        }` will execute in both first time run and when I check **Dont Ask Again** and deny the request!

Comment: no, it will not, last else will executed only when user check **Don't Ask Again** and also deny the request, because when you install the app, the system ask you to accept all permission that needed for the app before continue installing, so when you accept that and run your app for the first time, checkSelfPermission will be granted and execute code inside that condition, because as i said before **you already have granted all permissions needed for the app before continue installing.**

Answer (score 1):

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      //initilize your views


    if(iscontactsAllowed){

    // do your code here

    } else {

     requestcontactsPermission();

    }

}
private void requestcontactsPermission() {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {
            //If the user has denied the permission previously your code will come to this block
            //Here you can explain why you need this permission
            //Explain here why you need this permission
            Log.d("scancode", "denied permission before");
        }

        Log.d("perm", "fourth");
        //And finally ask for the permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, READ_CONTACTS_CODE /*can be any interge */);

    }

private boolean iscontactsAllowed() {
            //Getting the permission status
            int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);

            //If permission is granted returning true
            if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)

                return true;

            //If permission is not granted returning false
            return false;
        }


@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        //Checking the request code of our request

        if(requestCode == READ_CONTACTS_CODE){

if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

// you have the permission call yur method here

} else {

// permission denied show user why you need it or ask again by calling reuestpermission if you need the permission
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

@ArtinArtin I have expanded on @salmanyahya updated simple code and provided my logic with Alert Dialog's and one Snackbar (not a big fan of Snackbar's) any way see if this helps

```
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //.... write file into storage ...
            System.out.println("SDK > BuildVersion TRUE");
        } else {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 666);  // Comment 26
            System.out.println("go to requestPermissions");
        }
    }
    onLoad();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {

        case 666: // Allowed was selected so Permission granted
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                Snackbar s = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),"Permission Granted",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                View snackbarView = s.getView();
                TextView textView = (TextView) snackbarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                textView.setTextSize(18);
                textView.setMaxLines(6);
                s.show();

                // do your work here

            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && !shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permissions[0])) {
                // User selected the Never Ask Again Option Change settings in app settings manually
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Change Permissions in Settings");
                alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage("" +
                                "\nClick SETTINGS to Manually Set\n"+"Permissions to use Database Storage")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("SETTINGS", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                                intent.setData(uri);
                                startActivityForResult(intent, 1000);     // Comment 3.
                            }
                        });

                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();

            } else {
                    // User selected Deny Dialog to EXIT App ==> OR <== RETRY to have a second chance to Allow Permissions
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Second Chance");
                    alertDialogBuilder
                            .setMessage("Click RETRY to Set Permissions to Allow\n\n"+"Click EXIT to the Close App")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("RETRY", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    //ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, Integer.parseInt(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE));
                                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    startActivity(i);
                                    }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton("EXIT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    finish();
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
            }
            break;
    }};
```

Answer (score 1):

This code helps to handles the run time permission Management in Android

```
public String storagePermissions = Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;   
private static final int REQUEST_ACCESS =101;  

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
      if(checkSelfPermission(storagePermissions)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
          result();    // result  is your block of code 
      }else {
          requestPermissions(new String[]{storagePermissions},REQUEST_ACCESS);
      }

    }
    else{
        result();    //so if user is lower than api verison M, no permission is requested
    } 

}

 private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setTitle("Hi User..")
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", okListener)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {        //idea calling showMessage funtion again
                    Snackbar mySnackbar = Snackbar.make( findViewById(R.id.coordinatorlayout),"You Press Cancel.. ", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                    mySnackbar.setAction("Exit", new cancelButton());
                    mySnackbar.show();

                }
            })
            .create()
            .show();
}


private void result(){
          //your code
}

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public class NeverAskAgain implements View.OnClickListener{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        goToSettings();
    }
}
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void goToSettings() {
    Intent myAppSettings = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
    finish();
    myAppSettings.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    myAppSettings.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivityForResult(myAppSettings, REQUEST_APP_SETTINGS);
}
public class cancelButton implements View.OnClickListener{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"To use this app , you must grant storage permission",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        finish();
    }
    }


 @Override
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions,grantResults);

    switch(requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_ACCESS:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // permission is granted
                    result();
                    break;
                }
                else if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permissions[0])){
                    showMessageOKCancel("You choose Never Ask Again,option",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Snackbar mySnackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.coordinatorlayout), "Permission=>Storage=>On", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                        mySnackbar.setAction("Settings", new NeverAskAgain());
                        mySnackbar.show();
                    }
                     });
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    showMessageOKCancel("You Denid permission Request..",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            requestPermissions(new String[]{storagePermissions}, REQUEST_ACCESS);
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I have found is that shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale only returns true if the user has denied permission (at least once) and not selected "Don't Ask Again". Meaning, it won't be displayed on the first time the permission is requested either.