# Permission popup doesn't show on Android 7.0, shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale always false

Tags: java, android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, android-7.0-nougat

I have a react native app, I use this java code to check the camera permission :

```
int permission = PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(getReactApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA);

if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
       ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CAMERA);
}

promise.resolve(permission);
```

On Android 6.0, when the camera permission is off, the native permission popup shows thanks to the requestPermissions function.

However, it doesn't show on Android 7.0.

I checked the result of :

```
ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
```

It's false on Android 6.0 and 7.0

Thanks for your answer,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android M Permissions : Confused on the usage of shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32347532/android-m-permissions-confused-on-the-usage-of-shouldshowrequestpermissionrati)

Answer (score 0):

This is how we check and manage all the end user input when dealing with permissions just change to the permission you want to deal with

First check

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        } else {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 666);  // Comment 26
        }
    }
```

Then manage end user input

```
    @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {

        case 666: // User selected Allowed  Permission Granted
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                Snackbar s = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Permission Granted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                View snackbarView = s.getView();
                snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                TextView textView = (TextView) snackbarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                textView.setTextSize(18);
                textView.setMaxLines(6);
                s.show();

                // do your work here

                // User selected the Never Ask Again Option Change settings in app settings manually
            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && !shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permissions[0])) {

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Change Permissions in Settings");
                alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage("Click SETTINGS to Manually Set\n\n" + "Permissions to use Database Storage")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("SETTINGS", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                                intent.setData(uri);
                                startActivityForResult(intent, 1000);
                            }
                        });

                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();

            } else {
                // User selected Deny Dialog to EXIT App ==> OR <== RETRY to have a second chance to Allow Permissions
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Second Chance");
                alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage("Click RETRY to Set Permissions to Allow\n\n" + "Click EXIT to the Close App")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("RETRY", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("EXIT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                finish();
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
    }
    break;
    }};
```