# java.lang.StackOverflowError when request for runtime permission

Tags: java, android, runtime-permissions

I have created a common class `PermissionManager` for manage all permission from a single place,normaly it's working fine but after upload it showes error report on crash analytics i am not able to reproduce that,details are mentions below

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
       at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:308)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:400)
       at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:409)
       at com.mypackage.permission.PermissionManager.checkLocationPermission(PermissionManager.java:46)
       at com.mypackage.activities.SplashActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(SplashActivity.java:98)
       at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(Activity.java:3857)
       at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityCompat.java:507)
       at com.mypackage.permission.PermissionManager.requestPermission(PermissionManager.java:105)
       at com.mypackage.permission.PermissionManager.checkPermission(PermissionManager.java:69)
       at com.mypackage.permission.PermissionManager.checkLocationPermission(PermissionManager.java:46)
       at com.mypackage.activities.SplashActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(SplashActivity.java:98)
       at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(Activity.java:3857)
       at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityCompat.java:507)
       at com.mypackage.permission.PermissionManager.requestPermission(PermissionManager.java:105)
       at com.mypackage.permission.PermissionManager.checkPermission(PermissionManager.java:69)
       at com.mypackage.permission.PermissionManager.checkLocationPermission(PermissionManager.java:46)
       at com.mypackage.activities.SplashActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(SplashActivity.java:98)
       at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(Activity.java:3857)
       at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityCompat.java:507)
       at com.mypackage.permission.PermissionManager.requestPermission(PermissionManager.java:105)
       at com.mypackage.permission.PermissionManager.checkPermission(PermissionManager.java:69)
       at com.mypackage.permission.PermissionManager.checkLocationPermission(PermissionManager.java:46)
       at com.mypackage.activities.SplashActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(SplashActivity.java:98)
       at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(Activity.java:3857)
       at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityCompat.java:507)
       at com.mypackage.permission.PermissionManager.requestPermission(PermissionManager.java:105)
       at com.mypackage.permission.PermissionManager.checkPermission(PermissionManager.java:69)
       at com.mypackage.permission.PermissionManager.checkLocationPermission(PermissionManager.java:46)
       at com.mypackage.activities.SplashActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(SplashActivity.java:98)
       at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(Activity.java:3857)
       at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityCompat.java:507)
       at com.mypackage.permission.PermissionManager.requestPermission(PermissionManager.java:105)
       at com.mypackage.permission.PermissionManager.checkPermission(PermissionManager.java:69)
       at com.mypackage.permission.PermissionManager.checkLocationPermission(PermissionManager.java:46)
       at com.mypackage.activities.SplashActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(SplashActivity.java:98)
       at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(Activity.java:3857)
       at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityCompat.java:507)
       at com.mypackage.permission.PermissionManager.requestPermission(PermissionManager.java:105)
       at com.mypackage.permission.PermissionManager.checkPermission(PermissionManager.java:69)
       at com.mypackage.permission.PermissionManager.checkLocationPermission(PermissionManager.java:46)
       at com.mypackage.activities.SplashActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(SplashActivity.java:98)
       at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(Activity.java:3857)
       at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityCompat.java:507)
       at com.mypackage.permission.PermissionManager.requestPermission(PermissionManager.java:105)
       at com.mypackage.permission.PermissionManager.checkPermission(PermissionManager.java:69)
       at com.mypackage.permission.PermissionManager.checkLocationPermission(PermissionManager.java:46)
       at com.mypackage.activities.SplashActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(SplashActivity.java:98)
       at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(Activity.java:3857)
       at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityCompat.java:507)
       at com.mypackage.permission.PermissionManager.requestPermission(PermissionManager.java:105)
       at com.mypackage.permission.PermissionManager.checkPermission(PermissionManager.java:69)
       at com.mypackage.permission.PermissionManager.checkLocationPermission(PermissionManager.java:46)
       at com.mypackage.activities.SplashActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(SplashActivity.java:98)
       at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(Activity.java:3857)
       at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityCompat.java:507)
       at com.mypackage.permission.PermissionManager.requestPermission(PermissionManager.java:105)
       at com.mypackage.permission.PermissionManager.checkPermission(PermissionManager.java:69)
       at com.mypackage.permission.PermissionManager.checkLocationPermission(PermissionManager.java:46)
       at com.mypackage.activities.SplashActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(SplashActivity.java:98)
       at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(Activity.java:3857)
       at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityCompat.java:507)
       at com.mypackage.permission.PermissionManager.requestPermission(PermissionManager.java:105)
       at com.mypackage.permission.PermissionManager.checkPermission(PermissionManager.java:69)
       at com.mypackage.permission.PermissionManager.checkLocationPermission(PermissionManager.java:46)
       at com.mypackage.activities.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:53)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6285)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:171)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**SplashActivity.java**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (PermissionManager.checkLocationPermission(this)) {

              // do the task
            }
    }

     @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PermissionManager.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION_ACCESS: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // do the task
                } else {
//                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "For find better result,enable GPS permission from setting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if (!PermissionManager.MY_REQUESTED_DIALOG) {
                        PermissionManager.checkLocationPermission(this);
                    } else {
                        startNextActivity(0);
                    }
                }


            }
        }
    }
```

**PermissionManager.java**

```
public class PermissionManager {

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 101;
    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION_ACCESS = 102;
    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA = 103;
    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL = 104;
    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_AUDIO = 105;

    public static boolean MY_REQUESTED_DIALOG = false;


    private static String[] storagePermission = new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
    private static String[] cameraPermission = new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA};
    private static String[] locationPermission = new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};
    private static String[] phoneCallPermission = new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE};
    private static String[] recordAudioCallPermission = new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO};


    public static boolean checkPhoneCallPermission(final Activity context) {
        return checkPermission(context, phoneCallPermission, "Permission necessary", "Allow call permission", MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL);
    }


    public static boolean checkStoragePermission(final Activity context) {
        return checkPermission(context, storagePermission, "", context.getString(R.string.storage_permission_rejected), MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }

    public static boolean checkLocationPermission(final Activity context) {
        return checkPermission(context, locationPermission, "", context.getString(R.string.location_permission_rejected), MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION_ACCESS);
    }

    public static boolean checkRecordAudioPermission(final Activity context) {
        return checkPermission(context, recordAudioCallPermission, "", context.getString(R.string.audio_permission_rejected), MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_AUDIO);
    }


    /*
     *
     * Check the permission
     *
     * */

    private static boolean checkPermission(final Activity context, String[] permission, String messageTitle, String messageDetails, int requestCode) {

        MY_REQUESTED_DIALOG = false;
        if (checkAPIVersion()) {
            if (checkPermissionStatus(context, permission)) {
                if (shouldShowRequestPermission(context, permission)) {
                    MY_REQUESTED_DIALOG = true;
                    showDialogForPermission(context, messageTitle, messageDetails, permission, requestCode);
                } else {
                    requestPermission(context, permission, requestCode);
                }
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return true;

    }

    /*
     *
     * Show dialog for why ,this permission is needed
     *
     * */
    private static void showDialogForPermission(final Activity context, String title, String message, final String[] requestedPermission, final int requestCode) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertBuilder.setCancelable(false);
        alertBuilder.setTitle(title);
        alertBuilder.setMessage(message);
        alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                requestPermission(context, requestedPermission, requestCode);
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    /*
     *
     * Request for permission
     *
     * */
    private static void requestPermission(Activity context, String[] requestedPermission, int requestCode) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context, requestedPermission, requestCode);
    }

    /*
     *
     * Check need to display dialog for permission access
     * executed when first time user decline the permission
     *
     * */
    private static boolean shouldShowRequestPermission(Activity context, String[] permissionCheck) {
        for (String permission : permissionCheck) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(context, permission))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /*
     *
     * Check list of permission is granted or not
     * if not requested for permission
     *
     * */
    private static boolean checkPermissionStatus(Activity context, String[] permissionCheck) {
        for (String permission : permissionCheck) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /*
     *
     * Check API version
     * if it's >=M need to check run time permission
     * */
    private static boolean checkAPIVersion() {
        return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M;
    }

}
```

can any one help to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an infinite loop which I'm guessing is caused by someone denying Location permission, and selecting the *"Never ask agan"* checkbox:

[image]

This will automatically deny any further requests for the Location permission. In your case this becomes a big problem as `PermissionManager::checkPermission()` prompts for the permission dialog using `showDialogForPermission()`, which is automatically declined, which in turn calls `onRequestPermissionsResult()`.

```
if (shouldShowRequestPermission(context, permission)) {
    MY_REQUESTED_DIALOG = true;
    showDialogForPermission(context, messageTitle, messageDetails, permission, requestCode);
} else {
    /* THIS LINE IS STARTING THE INFINITE LOOP */
    requestPermission(context, permission, requestCode); 
}
```

Because `shouldShowRequestPermission(context, permission)` is returning `false`, `MY_REQUESTED_DIALOG` is never set to `true` and the process loops over and over. My advice would be to break out of the permission process if both `shouldShowRequestPermission() == false` **and** your permission is declined in `onRequestPermissionsResult()`.

```
if (shouldShowRequestPermission(context, permission)) {
    MY_REQUESTED_DIALOG = true;
    showDialogForPermission(context, messageTitle, messageDetails, permission, requestCode);
} else {
    // Gracefully handle the fact that Location permission will never be granted
}
```

Comment: can you please update the code for `onRequestPermissionsResult` or explain little more about modification in `onRequestPermissionsResult` that needed

Comment: I've added what I believe to be the offending section of code to the answer.

Comment: `shouldShowRequestPermission` returning value of `ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` it's false if we nave not requested permission before,after first request it return true. As you mention if user click never ask again,it will return false.so how can i  identify difference between it's first time request so it return false and second user selected never ask again so it's false

Comment: Not able to answer that fully at the moment, but are you able to reproduce the issue yourself if you deny the request and click the "Never ask again" box?

Comment: please update it,if you identify any thing related to that

Comment: i think i found the solution for my issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32347532/android-m-permissions-confused-on-the-usage-of-shouldshowrequestpermissionrati

Answer (score 0):

That stacktrace is symptomatic of an infinite loop.