# OpenCV Manager installation in Android isn't working and Ccamera is not supported

Tags: android, opencv, augmented-reality

I want to develop an App for Android 4.0.1 in OpenCV (it is going to be used on Epson Moverio BT2000).There are happening some errors I can not solve.

I'm using OpenCV version 3.0.0 and I've followed the following tutorials: http://blog.codeonion.com/2016/04/09/show-camera-on-android-app-using-opencv-for-android/, which work on my cellphone (Samsung Trent GT-S7580 with Android 4.2.2).

When I try to run the aforementioned procedure on Moverio, the following error shows on the screen when I launch the application: "OpenCV manager package was not found. Try to install it".

In order to install it since there is no appstore or internet available I've installed the .apk. I've used the command line with

```
adb install < open_cv_manager_path.apk >.
```

This method works if I use my cellphone, but not for the Moverio Epson, which shows the following error in the command line:

```
"Sucess // rm failed for -f. No such file or directory"
```

And when running the application it now shows:

```
"It seems that your device does not support camera (or it is locked). Application will be closed ".
```

I belive the error is caused by the bad implementation of the OpenCV Manager in the Moverio, since in the samsung phone it works. Do you have any suggestion to solve this problem?

Best regards, Ricardo Gomes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is aparently a bug with openCV 3.0.0. The way I solved the problem was by changin g in the org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView.java, the line 127 "mCamera.setParameters(params); and remove it from the code (annotaded).

[Opencv: It seems that your device does not support camera(or it is locked)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987361/opencv-it-seems-that-your-device-does-not-support-cameraor-it-is-locked)